Как в js сделать отмену функции, что бы li_btn опять скрылся и это повторялось без перезагрузки страницы


var btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
var li_btn = document.querySelector('.li_btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  li_btn.style.display = 'inline-flex'
});
<nav class="menu_links">
  <div class="sun">
    <i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-sun"></i>
  </div>
  <ul class="li_btn">
    <li><a href="#">главная</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">практика js</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="btn">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
  </div>
</nav>




На этой картинке выполнен уже написанный код, то есть нажимаем на кнопку с 3 полосками и появляется меню навигации.
Как сделать чтобы при повторном нажатие меню опять пропадало?

Добавьте в вопрос больше информации и поясните, что такое "отмена функции"? Объясните суть кода, что он делает, что идет не так и желаемое поведение.

теперь понятнее вроде

Складывается ощущение, что код писали не вы... Вот у вас же в колбэке события клика прописано присвоение класса для меню. Перед этим надо добавить какой то if, который будет проверять текущее значение и менять его. что то вида if (li_btn.style.display === 'inline-flex') { ... } else { ... } Ну а внутри присваиваете нужные значения для display

я так уже пробывал делать, не выходит

При клике проверяйте текущее значение стиля display элемента и меняйте по желанию


const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
const li_btn = document.querySelector('.li_btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (li_btn.style.display === 'inline-flex') {
    li_btn.style.display = 'none'
  } else {
    li_btn.style.display = 'inline-flex'
  }
});
.li_btn {
  display: none
}
<nav class="menu_links">
  <div class="sun">
    <i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-sun"></i>Солнышко
  </div>
  <ul class="li_btn">
    <li><a href="#">главная</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">практика js</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="btn">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>Бутерброд
  </div>
</nav>




....так все настолько просто было, спасибо большое
